# combining 2 mains into a single program

Tags: java, arrays

Ok I asked this a couple days ago, but I didn't ask the right question.  I'm hoping someone can show me how to combine the following programs into a single program so each Main runs, one after the other.  They both compile and run fine, I'm just not sure how to combine them.

```
public class DieTest
{
   public static final int N = 6000;

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int[] d = new int[7];
      for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++) d[i] = 0;

      for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
      {
         int roll = (int)(6.0*Math.random() + 1.0);
         d[roll]++;
      }
      System.out.print("Rolls: " + N);
      for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
         System.out.print(", " + i + ": " + d[i]);
      System.out.println();
   }

}
```

and the second

```
public class Dice3
{
   public static final int N = 11000;

   public static int roll()
   {
      return (int)(6.0*Math.random() + 1.0);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int[] d = new int[13];
      for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++) d[i] = 0;

      for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
      {
         d[roll() + roll()]++;
      }
      System.out.print("Rolls: " + N);
      for (int i = 2; i < 13; i++)
         System.out.print(", " + i + ": " + d[i]);
      System.out.println();
   }
}
```

Comment: Do they have to be two separate `main`'s? Can they just be two separate methods that you call one after the other?

Comment: There is no reason for them both called with the **special** name `main`. So you just need to modify the name, and create a new `main` entry point.

Comment: They don't need to be 2 separate Mains no, any suggestions are appreciated.  I only wrote them originally as 2 mains.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (`main` is just a method like any other, it is only special because the JVM calls it when you run a class):

```
public class Combined {

    public static main(String[] args) {
        DieTest.main(args);
        Dice3.main(args);
    }
}
```

And then start the class `Combined` from the command line.